# TFS 2013 backslash in custom field

Tags: customization

I am trying to add a custom field in a work item template using TFS power tools. I add the new field and use the "ALLOWEDVALUES" rule to add some values. It allows me to put backslash character in the value field however when I try to save the work item, it throws an error: VS402504: User or group cannot be found: Category\SubCategory. Verify that the users and groups used in your work item type definition exist.

I could find a way to escape the backslash character. Is it not possible to put backslash characters in custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is supported in the filed value.

> **ALLOWEDVALUES**    Defines a list of allowed values for the field. Allowed values are values that are available for selection in a field
>   list on work item forms and in the query builder. You must select from
>   one of these values.

**Note:** When you use ALLOWEDVALUES to define a list of values that users can specify in a work item form or the query editor. **Users must specify one of the values in the GLOBALLIST or the set of LISTITEM entries.**

A sample of value for your reference：

```
<LISTITEM value="Emergency"/>  
<LISTITEM value="Major"/>  
<LISTITEM value="Minor"/>  
<LISTITEM value="Domain\joe"/>  
<LISTITEM value="[Global]\GlobalGroup" />  
<LISTITEM value="[Project]\ProjectGroup" />
```

More details about related info please take a look at official tutorial:  [Define pick lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/vsts/work/customize/reference/define-pick-lists?view=vsts)

For field pattern value: `^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+$`, also check the field definition [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/vsts/work/customize/reference/field-definition-element-reference?view=vsts).

---

Update:

If the field value contain backslash(`\`) characters, it will be parsed to an IdentityName(account) by default.  As a workaround, you could try to use  `/` instead.  Take a look at this similar question: [Is there any way to use a backslash in a TFS Global List value?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d06e2bc-c0e0-4e8f-abf5-51c6b947bde1/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-backslash-in-a-tfs-global-list-value?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

Comment: I understand that backslash is allowed but it treats the backslash as a special character and expects either an existing user or a group in the field. My custom field is just a set of categories and sub-categories and I am using backslash as a separator but TFS does not allow that. I was looking for a way to escape the backslash so that TFS treats it as a normal string.

Comment: @DevOpsy Have you tried to use \\ to treat it as \ in your field value, I could not make sure this works in the work item field value, but it worked other places.

Comment: @DevOpsy I have found something new, this seems to a expected behavior, if the field value contain backslash `(\)` characters, it will be parsed to an IdentityName(account) by default.  As a workaround, you could try to use  `/` instead.  Take a look at this thread  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d06e2bc-c0e0-4e8f-abf5-51c6b947bde1/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-backslash-in-a-tfs-global-list-value?forum=tfsworkitemtracking

Comment: Yeah, that's annoying. There should be a straight forward way to escape the backslash. Thanks for the workaround, I am using / as the separator.